# How to use a self-referencing Swift protocol as a type for a generic class

Tags: swift, generics

I'm stuck trying to create a linked list of generic nodes using a protocol. I realize there are fifty thousand linked list implementations out there. This is for educational purposes. I've looked over SO for related questions, and read all about protocols and such on swift.org. I've read a few articles about advanced usage on other sites, but I still haven't found something that addresses the problem I'm having.

It seems like a trivial issue; maybe I'm just not asking the right questions? Here's the stripped-down code:

```
protocol LinkableNode: class {
    func getNextNode() -> LinkableNode?
}

class LinkedList<T: LinkableNode> {
    var head: T?

    func detach() {
        head = head!.getNextNode()  // The call to getNextNode() is the problem
    }
}
```

I get `cannot assign value of type 'LinkableNode?' to type 'T?'` on the call to `getNextNode()`. I want `head` to be a node too, and I thought `T: LinkableNode` would do that, but obviously not. I've tried every permutation under the sun based on the few remotely similar examples I've found, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func getNextNode() -> LinkableNode?
```

defines a method returning a value of *some* type conforming to `LinkableNode`,
but that need not be the same type as the method is called on.

What you want is

```
protocol LinkableNode: class {
    func getNextNode() -> Self?
}
```

This defines a method returning an (optional) value of the same type as it is called on, and makes your remaining code compile.

*Side note:*  Unless you *want* your code to crash on an empty list,
use optional chaining instead of forced unwrapping:

```
class LinkedList<T: LinkableNode> {
    var head: T?

    func detach() {
        head = head?.getNextNode()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I am happy to add your name and a link to your answer to the comments of my code. Those comments will be very happy alongside the other comments in my code that thank you for your other SO answers! Cheers